# In zoom, is there a way to view who's talking while sharing screen in fullscreen view

Tags: macos, zoom-meeting

The above question especially when everyone has their videos turned off.
While not in fullscreen view, I get a small box saying "Talking: " in the zoom.us app on MacOS. Zoom app version: Version: 5.3.1 (52877.0927)

So while screen sharing, this is the only thing that's visible: [image] Any way to view, who's speaking? Similar case when someone else is sharing the screen.

Comment: What is the name and version of the web browser that you are using? Have you already tried to swicth to the different layouts? Have you already looked at the zoom.us help?

Comment: Added version details of the app. Yeah, can't do layouts while screen sharing. Yeah, I did look at the zoom.us help but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Just click the Participants icon in the toolbar in your pic. The  participants panel will pop out, and you can see all the participants and who’s talking by looking at the phone/mic icon next to the names of the participants.  So, it doesn’t explicitly tell you the name of the person who is speaking, you have to keep your eye on that panel and see who’s phone/mike icon is blinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the side-by side mode. You will see the cameras of the participants and whom is talking will be highligthed.

Also you could try the different "video layouts while screen sharing" (see the corresponding link below)

Resources

- [Side-by-side Mode for screen sharing](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115004802843-Side-by-side-Mode-for-screen-sharing)
- [Changing the video layout (Active Speaker View and Gallery View)](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362323-Changing-the-video-layout-Active-Speaker-View-and-Gallery-View-)
- [Video layout options while screen sharing](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360034188592-Video-layout-options-while-screen-sharing)

Comment: The first one "side-by-side mode" solution is exactly what I am looking for. But as you see in the above image, I don't have any "View Options" in that bar. Also, can't find any such option in the menu bar. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @subtleseeker Do you have dual-monitors enabled?

Comment: Nope, just single screen.

Comment: My Zoom Meeting version is 5.4.3... yours is 5.3.x - > try to update your app.

Comment: I updated the app but there is still no such option. On another zoom help page, I read that some views are active when there are more than 3 people in the meeting. I will wait for a meeting when someone shares their screens. I think I can view who's talking within a gray box when I am sharing but not when others are sharing. Will check in some time and return back. Thanks.